# Any way to make rsync based transfers faster using a staging directory

Tags: rsync, file-transfer, cwrsync

I rsync between two systems using ssh. The command line that I use is something like:

```
rsync -avzh -e "ssh" ./builds/2023_02_02 akamaicdn:builds/2023_02_02
```

The akamaicdn is accessed using ssh and the corresponding identity, host name etc are specified in ~/.ssh/config file.

Most of the times the destination dir doesn't exist. That means it is a full upload after rsync optimizations.

But the content that gets uploaded next day has lot of things similar to the ones from previous day as these are build dirs and we have lot of common content between them.

Is there any way to tell remote rsync to use set of previous dirs to scan when it is determining what parts of a file have to be uploaded?

I am open to other optimizations if you can think of.

Comment: Doesn't that work by default? I `rsync -R` a directory with tests to a remote node almost every day at work, and it never uploads files that didn't change on my side compared to remote side. I see a list of files it uploads in the `rsync` output and if I changed just one file, it will be the only one I will see in the output.

Comment: That is right when you are targeting a dir with content. In my case, I am uploading daily build dir to remote site. The daily build dir doesn't exist on remote site.

Comment: I'm confused: so, do you want to avoid re-uploading files to remote site in cases where the files on the remote site do not exist? But they have to appear somehow there. So the only other way I see is: you run a script on the remote site that may copy the older build directory to the newer place, and then you run a `rsync`. In that case files will appear on the remote site before running `rsync`, so that will allow to make use of the `rsync` optimization.

Comment: Lets say I uploaded 2023_02_02 dir today. Tomorrow I will be uploading 2023_02_03 dir. But this dir has lot of content that exist in 2023_02_02 dir that was uploaded already. Is there a way to do this without having to duplicate 2023_02_02 as 2023_02_03 first on remote site and then upload?

Comment: I found --compare-dest or --link-dest options are meant for this. rsync on the remote system will check if the dirs passed in those parameters have the file being processed. If available, it will be used as basis to figure out anything from source needs to be uploaded.